# Audio Buffer to blob to url not working Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this func:

```
const fetchAudio = async () => {
   const res = await fetch(audioUrl);
   const buffer = await res.arrayBuffer();
   const decodedBuffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(buffer);

   const blob = new Blob([decodedBuffer], { type: 'audio/wav' }); // I tried with both buffer and decodedBuffer here
   const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

   setDataPoints(decodedBuffer);
   setUrl(url);
}
```

And then this audio tag:

```
<audio>
  <source src={url} type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

And it doesn't work. If I click to preview the URL, it also doesn't work. But the buffer is ok because the audio wave renders correctly.

Comment: WAV/PCM audio files usually require you to manually include the file headers when you save them. I'm not sure what you have in `audioUrl`, but I believe that `decodedBuffer` does not have the WAV headers, only the data. Take a look at [this page](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422-winter-2014/projects/WaveFormat/) for a detailed description of the WAV file headers.

Comment: @eventHandler thanks man I searched a little bit more thanks to your observation and found a comment of other user pointing that I should create the blob before decoding, just posted an answer in here if anyone ever has the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Well thanks to @eventHandler and @JohnDoe I could fix it, for anyone having the same problem:

> Note that if you need to decode the arrayBuffer, this will detach the buffer, thus you won't be able to create the blob. Solution: get the array buffer, create the blob, decode the array buffer.

So basically, change the code to create the blob before calling `decodeAudioData`, since that fn modifies the original `buffer` object.

So that would be:

```
const buffer = await res.arrayBuffer();
const blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: 'audio/wav' }); 
const decodedBuffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(buffer);
```

and then you can use the blob to create the URL and use it in the Audio tag